# Fetching data filtered by system properties "CreatedAt" using Azure Mobile Services

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I am using Azure Mobile Services in my MVC project. I want to fetch records filtered by `CreatedAt` (which is an Azure table system property)

Following is the code I am using:

```
IMobileServiceTable<QuestionItem> bussinessQuestionItemTable =
    CustomDeclaration.MobileService.GetTable<QuestionItem>();
queryToPass = "$filter=__createdAt ge datetime'2014-10-25T04:06:27Z'";
var coll = await bussinessQuestionItemTable.ReadAsync(queryToPass);
```

It always throws an exception `The request could not be completed.  (Bad Request)` with StatusCode:400

I tried the same query with a `DateTime` field created by us and it worked fine, but it always fails with `CreatedAt`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In the .NET backend, the type of the `CreatedAt` column is `DateTimeOffset`, not `DateTime`. So to query based on that property you'll need to use the corresponding literal in your query:

```
IMobileServiceTable<QuestionItem> bussinessQuestionItemTable =
    CustomDeclaration.MobileService.GetTable<QuestionItem>();
queryToPass = "$filter=__createdAt ge datetimeoffset'2014-10-25T04:06:27Z'";
var coll = await bussinessQuestionItemTable.ReadAsync(queryToPass);
```

Notice that if your type `QuestionItem` has a property tagged with [CreatedAt] (or [JsonProperty("__createdAt")] **of type DateTimeOffset**, then you can use a linq query as well:

```
IMobileServiceTable<QuestionItem> bussinessQuestionItemTable =
    CustomDeclaration.MobileService.GetTable<QuestionItem>();
var coll = await bussinessQuestionItemTable
    .Where(q => q.CreatedAt >= new DateTimeOffset(2014, 10, 25, 4:, 6, 27, TimeSpan.Zero))
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: It worked using query string but fails with Lambda Expression.

Comment: How does it fail? How is your type defined on the client?

Comment: Thanks Carlos, it worked using query string but fails with Lambda Ex. 
When using Lambda Ex I found out that its formed RequestUri contains "datetime" in the string instead of "datetimeoffset". 
Here is it - 
"https://abc.azure-mobile.net/tables/QuestionItem?$filter=(__createdAt ge datetime'2014-10-24T22:36:27.000Z')&__systemproperties=__createdAt%2C__updatedAt"

I tried passing the same query string replacing datetime with datetimeoffset and it worked. Here is the query I used - 
"$filter=(__createdAt ge datetimeoffset'2014-10-24T22:36:27.000Z')&__systemproperties=__createdAt%2C__updatedAt"

Comment: [CreatedAt]
public DateTimeOffset CreatedAt { get; set; }

Comment: You may be using an old version of the client SDK; the support for DateTimeOffset was added in version 1.2.4 - see [changelog](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) and [the actual change](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/commit/fc9b2510f781d994fa8e4f6ef8730ea4bdfc88c7)